# What to do when the following maven dependency org.hibernate.query.QueryParameter cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, maven-plugin

I am using eclipse Oxygen 3, march 2018.

[image]

Comment: I cannot find this org.hibernate.query.QueryParameter dependency no matter where I searhc, it isn't included in any .jar library. I am trying to download it and then import it into project as an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding :

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
<version>3.2.6.ga</version>
```

to your pom.xml?